# CVE-2020-27216 vulnerability on windows machine

Tags: windows, security, jetty

Recently this vulnerability was flagged on Jetty.
**CVE-2020-27216**

In Eclipse Jetty versions 1.0 thru 9.4.32.v20200930, 10.0.0.alpha1 thru 10.0.0.beta2, and 11.0.0.alpha1 thru 11.0.0.beta2O, on Unix like systems, the system's temporary directory is shared between all users on that system. A collocated user can observe the process of creating a temporary sub directory in the shared temporary directory and race to complete the creation of the temporary subdirectory. If the attacker wins the race then they will have read and write permission to the subdirectory used to unpack web applications, including their WEB-INF/lib jar files and JSP files. If any code is ever executed out of this temporary directory, this can lead to a local privilege escalation vulnerability.

My question is regarding windows. Is that an issue on windows?
Because of *'on Unix like systems, the system's temporary directory is shared between all users on that system.'*

I couldn't find anything to support that windows has something like this.
https://superuser.com/questions/906023/temp-directory-for-all-users

But again some people mentioned that it depends on application as well. So how can I decide whether its a security vulnerability on windows 2016 server.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your system.

Run the command (on the command line) ...

```sh
> java -XshowSettings:properties --version
```

Look for the `java.io.tmpdir` value, if it points to `%SYSTEMROOT%\Temp` (or other non-user specific directory) then you are vulnerable.